# What is a good practice for creating test case in a class where one function calls other function of same class in Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a Util.java class which contains some functions as follows:

```
public Util {
    UtilB b;

    funcA() {
        //someAction
        String a = b.someMethod();
        funcB();
    }

    funcB() {
        //recursive call to funcB
        funcC();
    }

    funcC() {
        //some processing
    }
}
```

While writing test case in Mockito, I did something as follows:

```
public UtilTest {

    @Mocks
    UtilB b;

    @InjectMocks
    Util test;

    @Test
    public funcA() {
        when(b.someMethod()).thenReturn("");
        test.funcA();
    }
}
```

As can be seen above, I cannot mock a call to funcB() when funcA() is called. The call will go inside funcB(). I can shift `funcB()` in another class like `someMethod()` in `UtilB` and mock that class like `UtilB b` and the test will work without actually calling funcB(), but is that a good practice to go on about creating new classes?

Additionally, since I am testing class Util, it should not be good to make it a spy and then operate on it to mock a call to funcB() right?

Should I even Mock funcB() in the first place since `test.funcA()` will cover funcB() and funcC() as well?

Could someone please guide me what is a good practice in this scenario?

Comment: Why can't you do `when(test.funcB())`?

Comment: Is this your real code? Otherwise, I suspect this is an XY problem and you might want to try refactoring the code

Comment: @cricket_007 `when(test.funcB())` will not work as `test` is a real instance and not a mock. I cannot understand what kind of refactoring? I can create a new class, say ClassB, for funcB(), mock it with name "classB" and then `when(classB.funcB())` will not call actual function and work as expected. This exactly is my question that do we need to create new class? Is it a good practice that whenever we stumble upon similar scenarios, we go on creating new classes?

Comment: I'd need to see your real code to say if you need a new class. Sometimes you just have interfaces, not only classes. And you can follow TDD patterns to write better tested code

Comment: You have a wrong understanding of what Mocks do. Mocks replace *dependencies*, that is: classes that do not belong to your code under test providing their own business behavior. Any code inside the class you're testing is *implementation detail* and should not be mocked.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle So does that mean funcA(), funcB() and funcC() in my question should not have separate @Test? So `test.funcA()` in UtilTest in question is correct and I must not mock funcB() and funcC()?

Comment: @cricket_007 As Timothy pointed out, is it even good that I am planning on mocking funcB()? I am editing my question to include this aspect as well

Comment: Again, I'd have to understand your real code to advice what you could do

Comment: @FeatherRidgemont Yes. either they are your *internal implementation detail* which means they should not be visible outside the class or they are *units of their own* in which case they should live in their own classes (and have own tests) being replaced by mocks when testing other units depending on them.